# Bulk Edit Products in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm

On Product entity views, I am not able to **Edit** multi-selected Products in CRM 2015 Online. Also tried by keeping the Products in Active as well as in Draft mode.

Is is supposed to be like this? Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM 2015 doesn't allow editing Products in bulk (unlike previous versions). The new structure which implements families and bundles is to blame for this.